# Why the two outputs are different?

Tags: pattern-matching

My first code is `{a, b, b, a, b, a, b, a, a, b} /. {___, x : Longest[PatternSequence[a, b] ..], ___} :> {x}` and its output is {a,b,a,b}.
The second code is `{a, b, b, a, b, a, b, a, a, b} /. {___, x : Repeated[PatternSequence[a, b], 2], ___} :> {x}` while its output is {a,b}.
Why the second code can't find double {a,b} in the list?I'm a little confused and Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Repeated[pattern, n]` matches the first instance of `pattern` repeated *up to* `n` times. So it matches just one `a,b` at the very start of the list here, says "I've now matched the pattern between 1 and 2 times", and stops successfully. Consider using `Longest[Repeated[...]]` to get the longest match, as you do, or `Repeated[pattern, {n}]` to match exactly `n` repetitions of the pattern, or `Repeated[pattern, {n, m}]` to match between n and m repetitions of the pattern. hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that in the absence of an explicit `Longest` or `Shortest` specification, ordinary expression patterns assume `Shortest`.  The pattern `Repeated[PatternSequence[a, b], 2]` will match at least one and at most two occurrences.  Because of the `Shortest` default, a match of length one is used. (See the *Details* sections for [Repeated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) and [Shortest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html).)

To force a match of exactly two occurrences we can use:

```
{a, b, b, a, b, a, b, a, a, b} /.
  {___, x : Repeated[PatternSequence[a, b], {2}], ___} :> {x}
```

Or to force the longest match (in this case of length up to two):

```
{a, b, b, a, b, a, b, a, a, b} /.
  {___, x : Longest@Repeated[PatternSequence[a, b], 2], ___} :> {x}
```